# opencvsharp "OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Scalar' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, opencv

I am trying creating image and draw rectangle 
While I was studying c++ I use this code:

```
Mat image =Mat::zeros(RectangleX, RectangleY, CV_8UC3);
```

and for drawing rectangle I use this code :

```
rectangle( image, Point( X.x1, Y.y1 ), Point( (sayi.widht1+X.x1), (heights.h1+Y.y1)), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), -1, 4 );
```

But now I am studying c# and I use this code:

```
Mat image = new Mat image(RectangleX, RectangleY, BitDepth.U8,1);
```

and these :

```
Cv2.Rectangle( image, Cv.Point( cx.x1, cy.y1 ), Cv.Point (w.widht1+cx.x1, h.height1 +cy.y1),    Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), -1, 4 );
```

But I have these errors :
1) Scalar OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Scalar' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
2) I cant create an image 
How I can create image an draw rectangle ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "x is a variable but is used like a method" syntax error in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081031/how-to-fix-x-is-a-variable-but-is-used-like-a-method-syntax-error-in-c)

Comment: `new Cv.Point...` and `new Scalar...` probably

Comment: no I tried this method but new cv.point and new scalar for opencvcharp 3x I used opencvsharp 2

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows you to create a new instance of a class either with or without `new`. C# only allows the syntax with `new`.

Comment: I tried this : Mat image = new (RectangleX, RectangleY, BitDepth.U8,1); but I have an error :

Comment: @stackopen: the `new` goes immediately before the type.

Comment: I tried  : Mat image = new  Mat(RectangleX, RectangleY, BitDepth.U8,1); but I have an image